# Is there any way to get tag's argument in a web page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm looking for the way to collect/scrape tag's arguments in a web page.

One of the tag I want to extract argument is following:

```
<div style="display:block;height:3px;width:47px;background-position: -5px 0px" class="resource_graph_70px"></div>
```

in there, I want to collect '47'. the one in 'width:47px'.

I have no idea about collecting those arguments. So I hope anyone can help me with this.

Thank you for your helps in advance!
Have a nice day.

Comment: This is not an argument, it's an attribute of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".resource_graph_70px")
element.value_of_css_property("width")
```

The output will be: `47px`.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I can't believe I didn't add a comment for this!
Thank you very much Ratmir! You really saved my life xD